# ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "dailysteps"

Tags: sql, left-join, inner-join, pgadmin-4

I am trying to inner join two copies of the table `ActivtiyDay` so I was assuming I could go ahead and join on these columns. The syntax that I am trying to use:

```
SELECT ds.id, ds.ActivityDay, ds.StepTotal, dc.id, dc.ActivityDay, dc.Calories
FROM public."dailySteps" as ds
LEFT JOIN public."dailyCalories" as dc
on public.dailySteps.ActivityDay = public.dailyCalories.ActivityDay
```

I have declared the correct columns from each table and I have declared each table that I am going to use.

Why is it throwing this error?

```
***ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "dailysteps"
LINE 8: on public.dailySteps.ActivityDay = public.dailyCalories.Acti...
           ^
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 158***
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you declare a table alias, you must, from that point on, always refer to columns from that table via the table alias:

```
SELECT
      ds.id
    , ds.ActivityDay AS dsActvityDay
    , ds.StepTotal
    , dc.id
    , dc.ActivityDay AS dcActvityDay
    , dc.Calories
FROM PUBLIC.dailySteps AS ds
LEFT JOIN PUBLIC.dailyCalories AS dc ON ds.ActivityDay = dc.ActivityDay
```

nb: use the aliases in the join conditions also.

Comment: I tried using this code and it throws me this error: "ERROR:  relation "public.dailysteps" does not exist
LINE 8: FROM public.dailySteps AS ds". This doesnt make any sense to me because this table clearly exist

Comment: The ActivityDay columns mustn't have the same value, dc.ActivityDay can be null.

Comment: @BrandonSchultz we cannot resolve issues such as the table does not exist.  Check the spelling and or check that it isn't in a different schema.